# Converting MATLAB Code to OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I'm new to OpenCV and trying to convert the following MATLAB code to OpenCV using C++:

```
    [FX,FY]=gradient(mycell{index});
```

I have tried the following so far but my values are completely different from my MATLAB results

```
    Mat abs_FXR;
    Mat abs_FYR;
    int scale = 1;
    int delta = 0;

    // Gradient X
    Sobel(myImg, FXR, CV_64F, 1, 0, 3, scale, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT);
    convertScaleAbs( FXR, abs_FXR );
    imshow( window_name2, abs_FXR );

    // Gradient Y
    Sobel(myImg, FYR, CV_64F, 0, 1, 3, scale, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT);
    convertScaleAbs( FYR, abs_FYR );
    imshow( window_name3, abs_FYR );
```

I also tried using filter2D as per this question, but it still gave different results: [Matlab gradient equivalent in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977936/matlab-gradient-equivalent-in-opencv)

```
Mat kernelx = (Mat_<float>(1,3)<<-0.5, 0, 0.5);
Mat kernely = (Mat_<float>(3,1)<<-0.5, 0, 0.5);
filter2D(myImg, FXR, -1, kernelx);
filter2D(myImg, FYR, -1, kernely);
imshow( window_name2, FXR );
imshow( window_name3, FYR );
```

I don't know if this is way off track or if it's just a parameter I need to change. Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**
Here is my expected output from MATLAB:

[image][image]

But here is what I'm getting from OpenCV using Sobel:

[image][image]

And here is my output from OpenCV using the Filter2D method (I have tried increasing the size of my gaussian filter but still get different results compared to MATLAB)

[image][image]

I have also converted my image to double precision using:

```
eye_rtp.convertTo(eye_rt,CV_64F);
```

Comment: Can you provide the results?(I mean your gradient image)

Comment: What is eye_rtp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct that you need to do a central difference computation instead of using the Sobel filter (although Sobel does give a nice derivative) in order to match `gradient`.  BTW, if you have the Image Processing Toolbox, `imgradient` and `imgradientxy` have the option of using Sobel to compute the gradient. (Note that [the answer in the question you referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21622872/2778484) is *wrong* that Sobel only provides a second derivative, as there are first and second order Sobel operators available).

Regarding the differences you are seeing, you may need to convert `myImg` to float or double before `filter2D`.  Check the output type of `FXL`, etc.

Also, double precision is `CV_64F` and single precision is `CV_32F`, although this will probably only cause very small differences in this case.

Comment: Thanks, they are all of type `cv::Mat`. For conversion, did you mean something like `myImg.convertTo(myImg, CV_64F)`? Unfortunately I end up with something like this: [link](http://imgur.com/T0FjINR)

Comment: @orikon The type I'm asking about is the elements in the `cv::Mat`. I'm wondering if the elements are integers.  For conversion, yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: ah I see, they seem to be `unsigned char*`

Comment: @orikon That's what I figured.  I don't know how `filter2D` handles it when `myImg` contains integers, but the computations might end up truncating or worse.  Try converting `myImg` to a `CV_32F` and then doing the filtering.