# gradient () function in Java (OpenCV API)

Tags: java, c++, matlab, opencv

From [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19021793/examples-of-matlab-to-opencv-conversions) I found out that there are functions that are directly compatible to Matlab. I am interested in knowing the gradient() function. But this seems unavailable in the Java API for OpenCV 3.0.0.
Does Java API hold a smaller/reduced version of OpenCV (C++) ??

Comment: Read more carefully that answer. The names there are for Matlab functions. You'll find out that you need `Sobel`, or `filter2D` to accomplish this in OpenCV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I Know, there is no gradient function in OpenCV (C++) either. You have to do either [`Sobel`](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#Sobel(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20int,%20int,%20int)) for each dimension (x and y), or [`Scharr`](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#Scharr(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20int,%20int,%20int)) or if you want to use an specific Kernel, you can use [`Filter2D`](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#filter2D(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20int,%20org.opencv.core.Mat)).

Also, you may take a look to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977936/matlab-gradient-equivalent-in-opencv), they explain how to mimic the Matlab gradient function.

Back to your question, the Java version should have, if not all, almost all the c++ functions. Of course, this will apply to the release versions only.